# JScript, string length

Tags: javascript, string

What I can use in "Microsoft JScript" instead `length()` with string. String class does not have Method `length()` or I did't find. What a best way to get string length?

Answer (score 3):

There should be a [length property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3d616214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use.  Note that it's not a method, but a property, so you call it via `myStr.length`, not `myStr.length()` (no parentheses).